# How to fix Brew install mysql on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I tried to install MySql by using HomeBrew on my mac. (for hive usage)

I tried:brew install mysql, but it gave me error and warnings as:

Error: You must `brew link pkg-config' before mysql can be installed

Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.

How should I fix this ? Thanks!

Comment: Step one is, as always: `brew doctor`. Fix whatever it says is wrong. If you have other package managers installed that you're not using, you may want to remove those.

Comment: I see my problem, thanks!